# best way to load images of database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am writing an online store with asp.net language

I have to read product's image from the SQL Server database and then show product's images in a data list.

Images on data list :

```
<img id='image1' src='<%# Eval("k_code", "Imagec.aspx?ImageID={0}") %>'/>
```

Code behind of `imagec.aspx` is:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.QueryString["ImageID"] != null)
    {
        string strQuery = "select m_code, k_Name1, k_pic, k_code from kalaid where k_code = @id";
        string strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SuperConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["ImageID"]);

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);

        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        cmd.Connection = con;

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            sda.Fill(dt);
        }
        catch
        {
            dt = null;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            sda.Dispose();
            con.Dispose();
        }

        if (dt != null)
        {
                Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])dt.Rows[0]["k_pic"];

                if (bytes != null)
                {
                    Response.Buffer = true;
                    Response.Charset = "";
                    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                    Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
                    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + dt.Rows[0]["k_name1"].ToString());
                    Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
                    Response.Flush();
                    Response.End();
                }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is speed

Can I change my code that increase page load speed?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using SQL 2012 or later, you could store the images in a FileTable enabled for full access rather than in a blob column.  The file table directory could then be either replicated to a web image folder for http access or exposed via a virtual directory pointing to the FileTable UNC path.  This method would allow you store and retrieve the images more efficiently while providing relational benefits of referential integrity for the product image and data.

Comment: thanks  **  
i read i can use "Generic Handler" ashx Instead aspx file to show image  **  
As well as i read that i use data reader instead SqlDataAdapter  **  
as well as i read that i can save  all record on cache  to not need connect to sqlserver for every image  **  
are these methods right for me?thanks

Comment: Rather than retrieve the image from code, I suggest a local image folder on the web server so that the client browser can retrieve the image over http.  That will take care of caching and provide the best performance.  Just sync the web image folders with the FileTable to replciate.

Answer (score 1):

save the url directory of image, dont save the image. :D

Comment: i cant save images on directory and i have to load image of database :(
use of datareader can improve speed?or ...?

Answer (score 0):

If you're loading set of small images you can join it in single image (in photoshop-like application), then load only one image, then show parts of it at the places needed.

Comment: image of products not static and user can change image of products

Answer (score 0):

Save the image at local disk and then save that address to db and access images with that saved name in the database

Answer (score 0):

1. Have a static process to dump the images from the database into actual image files on disk

Decoding bytes from a SQL query is a slow process. Only do it when the source changes. Or avoid the database altogether if possible

2. Host those files as a separate domain

e.g. if main site is shop.com, images are in i.shop.com

This enables modern browsers to load images in parallel with other page resources

This may require a collection of folder(s) and even sub-folders, depending on the number of images. Use an algorithm to work out what folder names to use. More than a few hundred images or folders per folder will cause performance issues

e.g. Example algorithm: For image id 1234567, it maps to i.shop.com/12/34/567.jpg